while using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud
My pom.xml as follows
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId> 
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId> 
            <scope>runtime</scope> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>

    </dependencies>

Description:
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)

The following method did not exist:
'void org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>(java.lang.Object[])'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener, was loaded from the following location:
jar:file:/C:/Users/Pradeep/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-cloud-context-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/BootstrapApplicationListener.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder, is available from the following locations:
jar:file:/C:/Users/Pradeep/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.3.1/spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder: file:/C:/Users/Pradeep/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.3.1/spring-boot-3.3.1.jar

Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener and org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder
Which Version of Spring cloud and Spring Boot to use to solve the error

I see Spring Cloud Context 1.3.6 mentioned there. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context . That's... very old.

Please add your pom/gradle file to the question. You probably are setting dependency versions that you should not be. Rather rely on spring boot parent managed versions.

added the pom.xml

So obviously spring-cloud-starter-hystrix is very old too. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-hystrix/1.4.7.RELEASE
